# What are the 25 ways to die in Crackdown 2?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, crackdown-2

In Crackdown 2 for the 360 there is an Xbox Live Achievement (possibly the same as a PS3 trophy) which requires you kill yourself in 25 different ways.  Does anyone know the list?

Comment: hahaha at first I was like "it requires you to kill yourself 25 different ways? that's messed up" but then the answer revealed that the achievement is just to die 25 different ways, not necessarily at your own hands

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**10 different ways to die** by getting Shot/Blown up:

- Shot with bullet
- Shot with harpoon
- Shot in the head
- Shot/blown up by chopper weapon
- Shot/blown up by a turret weapon
- Blown up by grenade/ satchel charge
- Blown up by rocket
- Blown up by proximity mine
- Blown up by exploding object
- Blown up by Quacker

**8 different ways to die** fom Melee/Physics (ab)use:

- Hit by player ground strike
- Hit by player with held object
- Hit by driven vehicle
- Hit by chopper Blades
- Hit by hand to hand melee
- Hit by thrown object
- Hit by the Ground (Falling)
- Killed while in a vehicle

**7 ways to die** from the different Enemy Types:

- Killed by Reaper
- Killed by Pounder
- Killed by Agent Reaper
- Killed by Heavy armored Cell
- Killed by Scrounger
- Killed by any cell
- Killed by any peacekeeper

Making a total of **25 ways to die**
([source](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showpost.php?s=fa070d61ea082f268717c8b6fafee0b7&p=3273421&postcount=6))

Comment: that is such an awesome list :D

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed xbox360achievements.org when I googled for it.  Also, great way to include the answer and the source.  How questions should be answered around here IMO.